# Nested list in dictionary with float error

Tags: python, dictionary, floating-point

I have this dictionary with a lot of keys and for each key there is a list of coordinates(x,y,r) each being there own list. I am running into a big problem when I am trying to access theses coordinate values. I get an error say `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`. I am try to convert my dictionary to a new one that is similar, but allows me to access these values.

For example,
Old: `{key: [[x,y,r],[x,y,r],...]`
New: `{key: [(x,y),(x2,y2),...]}`

The biggest problem is that they are floats and I cant seem to access them to change them into an integer values.

This is what my dictionary looks like but contains a lot more keys and those keys can/do contain more coordinates within the values list.

```
{'0-0.png'] : [[99.0, 11.0, 2.8284271247461903], [17.0, 30.0, 2.8284271247461903]]}
```

My ugly code:

```

```
def correct_coordinates(dic):
    big_first = 0
    big_second = 0
    first = 0
    second = 0
    while first < 82:
        image = '{}-{}.png'.format(big_first, big_second)
        if second < 14:
            im = '{}-{}.png'.format(first, second)
            if img_count < 4:
                new_coordinates = []
                for coors in dic[im]:
                    print(np.array(coors))
                    break
                new_coordinates = [c + (226 * img_count) for coors in dic[im] for c in coors]
                print(new_coordinates)
                break
                coor_226[image].extend(new_coordinates)
                second += 1
                img_count += 1
            elif img_count == 4:
                new_coordinates = [c + (226 * img_count) for coors in dic[im] for c in coors]
                coor_226[image].extend(new_coordinates)
                second += 1
                img_count = 0

        elif second == 14:
            im = '{}-{}.png'.format(first, second)
            new_coordinates = [c + (226 * img_count) for coors in dic[im] for c in coors]
            coor_226[image].extend(new_coordinates)
            big_f += 1
            big_s = 0
            first += 1
            second = 0

    final_coors = second_corrected_coordinates(coor_226)

    for k in final_coors.keys():
        arr = np.array(final_coors[k])
        arr = list(zip(arr[0::3], arr[1::3]))
        final_coors[k] = arr

    pickle.dump(final_coors, open('../data/corr_coor_dict.pkl', 'wb'))
```

```

The `big_first` and `big_second` are just refering to a larger image labeled with those values.

Comment: What is the "logic" behind `[x,y,r]` becoming `(x, y)`. Can you please show a sample of your code with the problematic section? it's hard to decipher and provide assistance with the current information provided.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to give helpful suggestions or a concrete answer without a bit of code, or a snippet (sample) of your dictionary data. Please provide the code you are using and dictionary, and we'll gladly help.

Comment: It is **not** necessary to add *Please Help!* to your title. It's very clear already that you need help, or you wouldn't be posting a question here in the first place. Avoid extraneous, useless noise in your title and question body, be specific about what you're asking, include the *relevant portions* of your code, and ask a *specific* question, and we can try to help. *Please help me* is not a question at all; you should also see [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/62576)

Comment: 'float is not iterable' probably means that one of your for loops is iterating over floats, when you thought it was iterating over lists. It's hard to tell from the provided information though.

Comment: Okay won't to it again. I just feel like my code might be even worse so I was trying to give a scenario  of the architecture instead but Ill add it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through dic items and then use list comprehension to generate the new value as the following:

```
dic = {'key1': [[5.3, 5.5, 1.1], [2.2, 3.3, 1.1]], 'key2': [[5.3, 5.5, 1.1], [2.2, 3.3, 1.1]]}
newdic = {}
for k, v in dic.items():
    newdic[k] = [(i[0], i[1]) for i in v]
print newdic
```

output:

```
{'key2': [(5.3, 5.5), (2.2, 3.3)], 'key1': [(5.3, 5.5), (2.2, 3.3)]}
```

you can also use dictionary comprehension instead of the loop, as the following:

```
dic = {'key1': [[5.3, 5.5, 1.1], [2.2, 3.3, 1.1]], 'key2': [[5.3, 5.5, 1.1], [2.2, 3.3, 1.1]]}
newdic = {k: [(i[0], i[1]) for i in v] for k, v in dic.items()}
print newdic
```

Comment: If using python <v3.x, might want to switch to `dic.iteritems()` or `dic.viewitems()`, to avoid making a copy.